# Is there any symbol for Alternate action switch?

Tags: switches, symbol

There are some switches, that looks like push-button switches, but acts like On-Off switches (i.e. can maintain contact). In one-press they turns-on (and looks slightly deeper), and in next-press, they turns off (and looks slightly higher),
like this one:
[image: https://www.fujielectric.com/products/operating_indicator/box/img/command_switch_ah164_165_165_2_04.gif]

I saw them frequently  ( in TV-sets, Water purifiers, old radios, etc. )

Now, is there any any circuit- symbol for them?

Comment: Push button - normally open.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat: It's a toggle switch, push-button style.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. A schematic diagram is concerned only with the *electrical behavior* of the switch — which sets of contacts are connected in what patterns, such as SPST, DPDT, etc.

The *mechanical behavior* of the switch is outside the scope of the schematic diagram, so there's no specific symbology associated with it, other than to perhaps put some sort of text note near the electrical symbol. The actual switch is specified in the Bill of Materials (BOM), usually with a specific manufacturer and part number, or a description of the relevant features if a specific part has not yet been selected.

Comment: "_A schematic diagram is concerned only with the electrical behavior of the switch ..._". Not quite. Industrial schematics have symbols for hand, foot, pressure, limit, roller, push, toggle, etc., switch _actuators_.

Answer (score 3):

No.  If you wanted to convey the concept of "alternate-action" (vs. "momentary") then you could use the symbol for a toggle switch even though physically it more resembles a push-button switch.

Comment: not only externally resembles ... some people tell it in the name push-button switch, though it is not. Erroneous use obviously?